# Can I use a fan speed controller to control a vent fan that uses PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) for speed control?

Tags: electrical, fans

I'm creating a vent system in my workshop, using 4" pipes and I need to put an inline fan in the system and I want to be able to control the speed remotely. While I'm linking to specific products (an inline duct fan and a fan speed control), I'm open to using other reasonably priced hardware.

I want to use a fan speed control that works with Home Assistant. I can use Z-Wave or Insteon, but could add a Zigbee controller if necessary. I've done a lot of searching for fans and fan controllers, but I could have missed just what I'm looking for.

The fan I'm planning on using is an [AC Infinity Cloudline S4](https://acinfinity.com/hvac-home-ventilation/inline-duct-fan-systems/cloudline-s4-quiet-inline-duct-fan-system-with-speed-controller-4-inch/). The controller I want to use is an [Embrighten Z-Wave Fan Controller](https://byjasco.com/enbrighten-z-wave-in-wall-smart-fan-control-white-almond). I want to stress I'm open to other hardware, as long as it's reasonably priced and lets me use something like Z-Wave for remote control of the fan speed. The S4 can come with a controller, but it only works with direct handling.
There's no remote system for control. The same company has more expensive fans, one with Bluetooth and one with WIFI, but they are not sharing their technical information, so I can use only their app to control the fan. Their documentation states their controller uses PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) to control the fan speed.

I know ceiling fan speed controllers do not use the voltage level to control speeds and have read [this answer in Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/95199/62562) about how they work. I've also looked up info on PWM and seen mention of using capacitors to control the power signal. I'm not clear if this is the same as how a ceiling fan controller works. Unfortunately, I can't find clear documentation on any Z-Wave or other remotely controlled fan controllers on just how they work.

I can think of several ways to work this out (if it's possible):

- find a duct fan I know works like a ceiling fan
- find a duct fan speed control that has Z-Wave or something else Home Assistant recognizes built in.
- understand how the Z-Wave fan controllers work so I can find one that does what is needed.

I would guess that most fan controllers would work the same way, but I don't want to risk starting a fire by acting on that assumption.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Thanks. I checked - it's SO easy for me to miss a slight difference like that. (Actually, it's part of a learning disability.) So are both Width and Wave modulation basically the same thing, or is it possible they're using a different term because it's something different? I'd think they'd stick with something everyone is used to rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Okay, I have no idea how I just mentally locked into wave instead of width. I'll correct the question.

Comment: If you're going this route, you might be better off shopping for a fan that ships without a speed control but is compatible with PWM speed controllers.

Comment: @keshlam The problem is finding one that is. The manufacturers for these things don't give much information, even when I email them. Apparently there's a big rush for these now, since people want them for their grow tanks for marijuana, so they're all marketing to that group.

Comment: For somewhat more money and with much better weather resistance (but often also vertical-mount only) you can buy Radon fans that are otherwise quite similar (at least power to airflow available) and **not** marketed to pot growers, nor having any particularly big rush on them. They are generally white housings... And the makers may be more responsive. I know some folks do speed control them.

Comment: Just a datapoint: I slapped a random PWM fan controller on my bathroom vent fan's circuit, and it seems to be working OK. I haven't tried one on the inline fan I'm currently using as a poor man's circulation return

Comment: @keshlam how long did you test run it? I've considered doing something like that as a test to see what I get, but I feel like, to do that, I have to buy a fan "blind," and hope it works. It might not work with my first one - so how many brands do I go through? It's all about luck - and if it works for, say, a 6 hour test run, it should work from then on, but I feel kind of funny about taking a fan and putting it in the crawlspace when I don't know for sure the two components should work together. (And I worry about things like what would happen if I forgot and left it on all night.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm going to start looking for that. The fan will go in the crawlspace, which, in this case, is a trapezoid beside my workshop. The roof is a barn roof, so I have that space between the shop wall and the side of the roof and it won't be hard to mount it in any particular orientation. I'll search, but do you, by chance, have any brand names or links that you know of off the top of your head or from people you know have done this with a radon fan?

Comment: I've had it running this way for a year or two. I might be _slightly_ concerned about stall risk at the lowest speeds, but mostly I've been operating on "If it happens, it must be possible." I have to admit that I *have* had a fan motor fail, but since the unit was probably 50 years old or more I am not at all convinced that the two were related; if it fails again, then I'll worry.  Brandnames are mostly out of scope here, but for reference mine is a NuTone.

Comment: @keshlam I just got a return email from the fan company (AC Infinity) that said to NOT do that. Of course, it might still work and they're just doing a CYA thing. Also, due to some phrases in the response and the use of language, I suspect there may be translation issues and I'm not clear if they completely understood my question.

Comment: Sigh. Well, I'm not going to promise it will work if they say it won't.

Comment: @keshlam And that's the heart of the matter: It's a crapshoot and all about luck unless I get clearer information. I re-read the email - took some effort to parse it, but I was able to figure out just what they meant. They did look at the link and made comments about that fan, but I'm not sure they read about it using PWM. They also said they varied the AC current to the fans, but from everything I've read, I find that hard to believe.